# How do I create a derived dict from an existing one using a list of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wish to create a shorter dict from an existing one using a list of keys.
As a (shortened) example I have a dict:

```
    Note: All CAPITELIZED IDENTIFIERS IN THE EXAMPLES ARE ENUMERATED AS STRINGS ELSEWHERE AND IMPORTED


COLS = {
DATE_COL: {"width": 10.0, "format": DATE_FORMAT, "num": True, "type": str},
PURPOSE_COL: {
    "width": 52.0,
    "format": BUSINESS_PURPOSE_FORMAT,
    "num": False,
    "type": str,
},
RECEIPT_COL: {
    "width": 13.0,
    "format": RECEIPT_AMOUNT_FORMAT,
    "num": True,
    "type": float,
},
CURRENCY_COL: {"width": 15.0, "format": CURRENCY_FORMAT, "num": False, "type": str},
EXCHANGE_RATE_COL: {
    "width": 13.0,
    "format": OANDA_RATE_FORMAT,
    "num": True,
    "type": str,
},
REIMBURSE_COL: {
    "width": 13.0,
    "format": GBP_AMT_FORMAT,
    "num": True,
    "type": float,
}
```

}

The list of keys from which I would like to use to create the new dict is ( as a shortened example ) is

```
keys = [EXCHANGE_RATE_COL, REIMBURSE_COL]
```

Comment: it would help if you could enumerate the strings yourself such that users can quickly replicate the issue in thier editors.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a very simple dictionary comprehension:

```
shorter = {key: COLS[key] for key in keys}
```